# WIN API User Privilege C++

Tags: c++, winapi, privileges

I'm trying to see if the user has the SeLoadDriver privilege. I've got the PLUID :

```
    PLUID pld;
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME, pld);
```

But now i'm not sure how to get a bool from the PLUID stating that the user has, or not, the privilege. I've read the related methods but it think that it might be an easy way of getting this directly from the PLUID value.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little more involved than that.

First you need to obtain the process token's privilege set (by calling `GetTokenInformation()`) then you scan the buffer that you've got from that (which is an array of `LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` structures) for the LUID that you get from `LookupPrivilegeValue()`. You can then use the `LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` that you've located and check to see if the `Attributes` contain the required flag (`SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` in your case).

Be aware that when you are checking for an enabled privilege you should also check that `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` is NOT set in the `Attributes` that you are checking; a privilege that has both `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` and `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` has been removed and is NOT enabled...